# Username with numbers only is not being able to load the GUI in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

With a user with a username with only a number, it is not possible to load the GUI.
Via ssh it is possible to login and via TTY, but not via GUI.

System information follows.

```
    # finger 123
Login: 123                      Name: 
Directory: /home/123                    Shell: /bin/bash
On since Fri Jul 10 10:01 (-03) on pts/0 from 10.0.0.30
   4 seconds idle
     (messages off)
No mail.
No Plan.
```

auth log output

```
# tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-12907.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 kernel: [70746.971349] rfkill: input handler enabled
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: X.Org X Server 1.20.8
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-177-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: Current Operating System: Linux bnth04 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=1639c49d-fb40-4347-b19e-741b0b29a749 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: Build Date: 06 April 2020  09:39:29AM
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: xorg-server 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: Current version of pixman: 0.38.4Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (==) FontPath set to:
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011built-ins
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loader magic: 0x55a8bb04f020
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module ABI versions:
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011X.Org Video Driver: 24.1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (++) using VT number 3
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 12907 does not belong to any known session
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "glx"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "qxl"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/qxl_drv.so
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module qxl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011compiled for 1.20.7, module version = 0.1.5
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl: Driver for QXL virtual graphics: QXL 1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 0.0.2
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Deferred Frames: Disabled
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Offscreen Surfaces: Enabled
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Image Cache: Enabled
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Fallback Cache: Enabled
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (==) qxl(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading sub module "fb"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "fb"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 1.0.0
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: #011ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Output Virtual-1 has no monitor section
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): EDID for output Virtual-1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Printing probed modes for output Virtual-1
Jul 10 10:25:37 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) qxl(0): Modeline "1024x675"x59.9   55.20  1024 1072 1168 1312  675 678 688 702 -hsync +vsync (42.1 kHz P)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Power Button: always reports core events
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0/event0"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "br"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1/event1"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "br"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/event3)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse'
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: always reports core events
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3/event3"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event3  - VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event3  - VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: device is a pointer
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/event2)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse'
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: always reports core events
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4/event2"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (**) VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event2  - VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event2  - VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: device is a pointer
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12918]: dbus-daemon[12918]: [session uid=1003 pid=12918] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12905]: Unable to register display with display manager
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event1  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event3  - VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: device removed
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) event2  - VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse: device removed
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: message repeated 3 times: [ (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"]
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[12907]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gdm3: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gsd-color[12077]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual-1: unable to get EDID for output
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gnome-shell[11996]: Could not open device /dev/input/event4: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.DeviceIsTaken: Device already taken
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gsd-color[12077]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual-1: unable to get EDID for output
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gnome-shell[12927]: The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gnome-shell[12927]: > Warning:          Unsupported maximum keycode 569, clipping.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gnome-shell[12927]: >                   X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gnome-shell[12927]: > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym Invalid
Jul 10 10:25:38 bnth04 gnome-shell[12927]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

Comment: Usernames beginning with something else than `[a-z]` are usually not allowed, for good reasons! Your username `123` conflicts with a user ids which are also just numbers like that. Just don't do that. See https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux

Comment: @pLumo I made it an answer before I saw you comment :)

Comment: `adduser` can do it with `--force-badname` option ;-)

Comment: ah dang it. I KNEW that :D Removed the comment and the parameter is a clear warning ;)

Comment: @pLumo I'm managing to create the user, what I can't do is load the GUI, do you know how to do that? on Ubuntu 18.04 it worked.

Answer (score 1):

That is as intended.

Usernames starting with digits are not allowed in Linux. Not just Ubuntu. It breaks commands like `chmod`.

[GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Disambiguating-names-and-IDs):

> **2.6 chown, chgrp, chroot, id: Disambiguating user names and IDs**
>
> Since the user and group arguments to these commands may be specified as names or numeric IDs, there is an apparent ambiguity. What if a user or group name is a string of digits? 1 Should the command interpret it as a user name or as an ID? POSIX requires that these commands first attempt to resolve the specified string as a name, and only once that fails, then try to interpret it as an ID. This is troublesome when you want to specify a numeric ID, say 42, and it must work even in a pathological situation where ‘42’ is a user name that maps to some other user ID, say 1000. Simply invoking chown 42 F, will set Fs owner ID to 1000—not what you intended.

The regex used for usernames is (unless you use adduser with the `--force-badname` option):

```
^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$
```

so it needs to start with a [a-z]. Regex from `man 5 adduser.conf`

Comment: In Brazil there is the CPF which is a number similar to the American Social Security Number (SSN), where my user base will authenticate with this number, and it has worked since Ubuntu 8.04 only now on 20.04 that presented this problem.

I have no problem creating the user, the problem is just loading the GUI.

Via tty the user is able to login, as well as through ssh.

Comment: That will be systemd then. That is what we use nowadays. And this goes back to Unix  before Linux even existed. If you look at the regex even capitals are not allowed since those usernames had a special meaning back in the day

Answer (score 0):

For documentation for other people who may have this problem, exchanging gdm3 for lightdm, and adding the module "pam_mkhomedir.so" in "/etc/pam.d/common-session" it was possible to login.